# In a mixed objc/swift module, Xcode always tries to include the module itself

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, objective-c-swift-bridge

This one is not easy to explain, but is also very annoying.

I'm working on a Cocoapods framework (in development mode) with objc and swift sources. Let's call it the "*SuperCompoment*" framework

Xcode auto generates the `SuperComponent-Swift.h` file, to make Objc classes visible from Swift ones.
Some Objc classes also includes Swift classes.

At compile time, in the `SuperComponent-Swift.h`, Xcode adds the line

```
#import <SuperComponent/SuperComponent.h>
```

... and fails to compile with the message: `SuperComponent/SuperComponent.h file not found`

Xcode tries to include the framework inside the framework itself!

If I manually edit the auto-generated file by commenting the #import, the project compiles perfectly. But Xcode auto-generates the file after each clean and before archiving the project!

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Xcode automaticaly adds the `#import <SuperComponent/SuperComponent.h>` line (since it do work without it), but if i'm kind with him by adding an empty `SuperComponent.h` file at the root of my framework, it compiles gracefully.